# android - opengles- how to render a dynamic list of objects and update positions for each frame

Tags: android, opengl-es, translate

Im working on an application for android that is using canvas operations to do all the drawing at the moment but Im switching everything over to opengles to gain performance. My only problem is I have no idea how to draw to screen a dynamically changing scene in opengles. I have a few questions so I guess Ill list them.

1.) How do I dynamically add onscreen objects based on a constantly changing list using opengles.

2.) Do I need to pass some kind of list/array/object container to the renderer or the GLSurfaceView itself.

3.) If I want to translate/move the objects according to an updated position how would I update the actual position vector in the container for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea already. I would pass your container to the renderer and on each `onDrawFrame(GL10)` call, iterate through the container and perform the drawing. It might be worth synchronizing over the container as well if you are going to add objects dynamically.

In terms of moving the objects. I assume that you will have image textures as well as an array of vertices defining a rectangle over which the texture should be drawn. You could, for each object, store the vertices of the rectangle. When 'moving' the objects I would probably recommend you simply alter the value of the vertices instead of using translate.

Perhaps It would be helpful if you provided a bit more information about what sort of things you are trying to draw and when/how you want to add new objects.

snippet of example code:

**Bubble**

```
public class Bubble{
    float[] boundingBox;
    int textureNumber;

    Bubble(int n){
       textureNumber = n;
       boundingBox[0] = 0; boundingBox[1] = 100; boundingBox[2] = 0;
       boundingBox[3] = 100; boundingBox[4] = 100; boundingBox[5] = 0;
       boundingBox[6] = 0; boundingBox[7] = 0; boundingBox[8] = 0;
       boundingBox[9] = 100; boundingBox[10] = 0; boundingBox[11] = 0;
}
```

**Renderer**

```
ArrayList<Bubble> bubbles;
FloatBuffer bubbleVertexBuffer;

onSurfaceCreated(..){
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12*4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    bubbleVertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
}

 onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){

   gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);

            int size = bubbles.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                Bubble b = bubbles.get(i);
                bubbleVertexBuffer.put(b.boundingBox);
                bubbleVertexBuffer.position(0);
                gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, bubbleVertexBuffer); 
                gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,4);
            }
        }    

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :) Im just totally drawing a blank on how to iterate through the container in order to draw my objects to screen in an GLSurfaceView. Its probably all the extra set up just making it foggy but for some reason its totally evading my understanding at the moment. For example how would I tell the renderer to draw each object if Im just pulling them from a list.

Comment: For the moment I just want to draw a plane for each object that I can apply an image to that I have stored on the phone and each object will have its own unique texture/image. I would be deleting and rebuilding the list of objects depending on the users current gps position and drawing images to screen according to that same position. I already have the whole set up running using the canvas operations but its really slow when you get up around 50 objects near you.

Comment: About moving the objects with vertices.....are you saying just update the matrices I have set up to represent my objects positions to the vectors of each object vertice?

Comment: I had the same problem with the canvas :) I've added a snippet of some code. Hope it helps. For multiple objects, you will need to change the values of the bounding box

Comment: :) dude Im going to try that right now....I feel kinda silly because I actually had the same kind of for loop used to draw my objects to the canvas lol. I just didnt think it would work in the ondraw method for some reason.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. It sounds as though all the images will be moving by the same amount which might mean `translate` is a better option.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot....I didnt get it to work with the code in my project just yet but Im going to play with it a bit and let you know how it comes out :)